# Trying to get a result based on grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

I'm possibily overcomplicating this, but essentially I have a table that contains:

- a receipt number
- a bill value
- an integer that reflects the type of bill (1, 2 or 3).

There's a line for each item that's sold, and there can be more than one item on each bill, so there can be multiple instances of the receipt number (e.g. if I sell two items on the same bill, there will be two entries in the table with receipt number 123)

What I'm looking for is a count (and potentially the value) of bills where they contain more than one **type** of bill.

This is actually in VFP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have:

ID, value, type

1, 10.00, 8

1, 20.00, 8

2, 15.00, 5

2, 16.00, 7

3, 30.00, 8

You would want to see a count of 1 and a sum of 31.00?

This seems to work in SQL, so I guess that there is something equivalent in vfp (no way can I remember!)

```
SELECT BillId, SUM(Value)  FROM 
    (SELECT BillId, SUM(Value) AS Value, COunt(Type) AS TypeCount  
    FROM Bills GROUP BY BillId, Type) AS InnerGroup
GROUP BY BillId, TypeCount
HAVING Count(TypeCount) > 1
```

Basically the second column will give you the sum and the number of rows will be the count.

Comment: yep, exactly it, bar the fact that the type should only be either 1 or 2.

Comment: had to modify it slightly to include the typecount in the final result, so the initial line I got is: SELECT BillId, SUM(price), typecount FROM... but other than that, perfect.  Ta!

Comment: No probs, make sure you tell them where you got it from. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Without having your table structure, I improvised...

```
SELECT ;
      rcptNum, ;
      COUNT( distinct BillType ) DistTypes, ;
      SUM( billValue ) TotalBill;
   FROM ;
      Bills ;
   GROUP BY ;
      rcptNum ;
   HAVING ;
      DistTypes > 1;
   INTO ;
      CURSOR C_YourResults READWRITE
```

You can only have ONE COUNT( DISTINCT ... ) in a Query, so I've done it against your Bill Type column.  Then applying the HAVING clause to get those that had more than one type.